# How could I solve a peer dependency conflict?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I read some articles about peer dependencies, I know it's usually used in a plugin's package.json file.

For example, if I had a project and installed a package A (npm<3 || >7) with a peer dependency of package B, then the directories may look like:

```
Project
  |__node_modules
     |__package A
     |__package B
```

If my project already had a dependency of package B (v1.x).

Then I installed a package A with a peer dependency of package B (v2.x).

Also I installed a package C with a peer dependency of package B (v3.x).

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to handle conflicting peer dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259024/how-to-handle-conflicting-peer-dependencies)
The easiest solution is to run npm install with the --legacy-peer-deps flag